# Import error: No module name sklearn.external.six

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am currently using anaconda 4.8.3 and want to display a figure of decision tree and i have install graphviz and pydotplus library in anaconda instead of this i am getting error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.six' .this is my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydot 
features = list(df.columns[1:])
features
```

This is my error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0b3416ce7fda> in <module>

        1 from IPython.display import Image
--->    2 from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
        3 from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
        4 import pydot
        5 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.six'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can import StringIO from module six directly, no need to downgrade scikit.

```
from six import StringIO
```

Answer (score 1):

Module sklearn.externals.six was removed in the scikit-learn version 0.23. To use it you have to downgrade to version 0.22. For that, you can do -

1. In jupyter notebook try :!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.22
2. In terminal: pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.22